# Wordpress : How to Resize Thumbnail in RSS

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I want to make RSS Thumbnail with size 150px for example.

[image: Example]

Comment: Have you tried anything? [This looks useful](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size). I used [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=wordpress+rss+thumbnail+size) to find it.

Comment: i put this code in function.php 

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-post-thumbnail-to-your-wordpress-rss-feeds/

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65617/add-a-post-thumbnail-to-an-rss-feed-with-custom-size